# Integrating Firebase Push Notifications in Nodejs app

Tags: node.js, firebase, push-notification

Leveraging MongoDB, Node.js, and Firebase for Seamless User-Service Provider Communication

I face a unique challenge – This application is a third-party service provider, and I have limited knowledge about the Android application linked to our service. The primary goal is to send notifications from application to the users of this Android app, which I have no direct control over.

The Android app is maintained independently, and I do not have access to its source code or any specific integration details. This poses a significant challenge as I need to find a way to communicate with this Android app in order to send relevant notifications.

I am seeking guidance on how to establish a connection between our application and the unknown Android app to enable the delivery of Firebase push notifications seamlessly. Any suggestions or insights on how to achieve this inter-app communication would be greatly appreciated.

For now I am able to communicate with the clients but not their users. I want to be able to send the notification from my client to their user who are using the apps.